# The authentication bot from the bot builder samples does not display pop up for Microsoft website

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, botframework

I am trying to add authentication bot from Azure Bot Service using node.js code. When I click on sign-on button it just displays pop up saying go to this URL `oauth://tokenID etc...`, and when click on yes, it just says you are now logged in. But ideally it has to open the Microsoft Webiste to authenticate.

```
  this.addDialog(new OAuthPrompt(OAUTH_PROMPT, {
      connectionName: process.env.connectionName,
      text: 'Please Sign In',
      title: 'Sign In',
      timeout: 300000
  }));
```

Comment: Are you certain your login isn't cached in your browser and/or that you aren't logged in elsewhere, as well?

Comment: I use the Bot framework to test. I provide the AppID and AppPassword. The authentication bot runs and just displays a pop which says "do you want to open this URL ouath://<token>/livechat" and when clicked on yes, it just displays a message saying "you are now logged in". 
but does not open the Microsoft site to login. 

I did check that am not logged in any where or its not cached.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is currently a bug between direct line and Emulator. As of version 4.4.x, "|livechat" is being appended to the token when OAuth is run through Emulator resulting in broken login experience.

You can track and add to the Github issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1655#issuecomment-512970472).

There is a potential workaround listed which may help, in the short term.

Hope of help!